# $A^k = I$ implies diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a square complex matrix with $A^k = I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix of the same size as $A$) for some positive integer $k$, does it follow that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Notice that the polynomial with simple roots $x^k-1$ annihilates the matrix $A$ so $A$ is diagonalizable.